# jQuery animation with css not working correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-animate

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I have a problem with my jQuery, I'm trying to change the the visibility of my articles and the padding-top when I scroll down. The problem is that I want to do the "animation" to be slow, but it change right away instead of slowly.

Here is my Section and

```
<section class="SectionDesignWhite Section2">
                <article class="textSec2">LOST OF TEXT</article>
                <article class="textSec2 PadLeft30">LOST OF TEXT2</article>
                <article class="textSec2 PadLeft30">LOST OF TEXT3</article>
        </section>
```

My Css code:

```
.Section2 article {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

My jQuery script:

```
     $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 450) {
            $('.Section2 article').css({"visibility": "visible", "padding-top": "50px"}, 'slow');
        }
    });
```

I hope that I have made it clear what I'm trying to create after been stuck for hours. Can't seem to find a working answer at all.

Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: You can't animate visibility, you'll have to use opacity instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `animate()` but it only works with some properties, in this case you can't animate `visibility` you can use `opacity` like this:

CSS

```
.Section2 article {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background:Red;
    padding-top: 100px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;/*Add this*/
}
```

Jquery

```
$('.Section2 article').css('visibility', "visible")
                      .animate({paddingTop: "50px", opacity : '1'}, 'slow');
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/3gREz/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 450) {
         $('.Section2 article').css('visibility', 'visible').animate({"padding-top": "50px"}, 'slow');
    }
    });
```